# Copy Complete Directory to C drive

Tags: windows, batch

[image][image]I want to Copy a Complete folder (*del folder*) from Network location to my C drive. I tied using following command **xcopy "\\mallard\#mallard\Deployments\del" "C:\" /i** in batch file its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using `/e` but its not copying "del" folder from network location to my C drive.

- Robocopy and XCOPY are both designed to copy the *contents* of your source folder specified into the destination folder specified. They do not copy the source folder *itself* but start working from *within* it.
- The `/e` parameter is useful as it will cause subfolders and **E**mpty subfolders to be included but even this will not cause the source folder *itself* to be copied.

## What happened when you ran the scripts previously?

The files from your network drive were copied into the *root* of your Windows folder.

## Solution:

This is easy to fix. All you need to do is to append `del` to the destination specified in your script; Robocopy will *create* this folder first, before copying the files into it.

**Change this:**

`robocopy "\\mallard\#mallard\Deployments\del" "C:\" /e`

**To this:**

`robocopy \\mallard\#mallard\deployments\del c:\del /e`

I removed the quotation marks as they don't do anything unless your file paths contain spaces, and also made everything lower case as capital letters are treated the same as lower case in Robocopy scripts. (This just improves readability slightly and doesn't make any functional difference.)