# Overwrite a existing file

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

There is a file  *fcc.xml* in `C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens`. I want to copy a different version of *fcc.xml* from a network share (`\\mallard\\#mallard\Deployments\del`) to `C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens`.

I tried using `XCOPY /s \\mallard\\#mallard\Deployments\del\fcc.xml C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens` but its neither copying nor overwriting.

Comment: *neither copying nor overwriting* `/Y`.

Comment: XCOPY /s \mallard\#mallard\Deployments\del\fcc.xml C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens /Y is it correct??

Comment: I tried using XCOPY /s \mallard\#mallard\Deployments\del\fcc.xml C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens /Y but its not Overwriting

Comment: Execute `xcopy /?` and investigate the output carefully.

Comment: i had executed xcopy but its not overwriting

Comment: If you run the same command in an interactive command prompt, does it error, e.g. `Sharing violation`?  Is the file in use?  Would you need to stop the process that has a handle to the file?

Comment: Is this fixed now? It sounds like it might be the same issue that you were having yesterday. https://superuser.com/questions/1508807/copy-complete-directory-to-c-drive

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
xcopy /y /f "\\mallard\\#mallard\Deployment\del\fcc.xml" "C:\ProgramFiles\Siemens"
```

Comment: The `/f` is redundant, it merely: "Displays full source and destination file names while copying." It has nothing to do with helping to overwrite files.